# how does list(string) split the string to an array of characters in python?

Tags: python

```
a = "Stack"
aList = list(a)
```

This gives me an array like this `['S','t',a','c','k']`

I want to know how this `list(string)` function works!

Comment: I am up-voting this to counteract the un-commented down-vote (an un-productive feedback). As you appear to be fairly new here, let me suggest that you read over the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), if you haven't already, and browse over several questions, noting common formatting and content conventions. Newbies are welcome here, so keep asking questions!

Comment: Python doesn't have arrays.  What are you asking?

Answer (score 7):

A string is an iterable type. For example, if you do this:

```
for c in 'string':
    print c
```

You get

```
s
t
r
i
n
g
```

So passing a string to `list` just iterates over the characters in the string, and places each one in the list.

Answer (score 4):

String is `iterable` in python because you can do

```
>>> for ch in "abc":
...         print ch
...
a
b
c
>>>
```

and if you take a look at `list` class `construtor` using `help("list")` in your python interpreter

```
class list(object)
 |  list() -> new empty list
 |  list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
```

So, `list("hello")` returns a new list initialized.

```
>>> x = list("hello")
>>> type(x)
<type 'list'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works because `str` implements `__iter__`, which allows `iter(obj)` to be called on the object. For `str`, the implementation returns character by character.

Comment: thanks everyone! I wanted to know exactly how the list() function worked. You people gave me a good idea about it!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the work is actually being done by the string. You are actually using the constructor of the `list` type. In Python, we are usually not so concerned with what things are, but rather with what they can do.

What a string can do is it can give you (e.g. for the purpose of using a for loop) its characters (actually, length-1 substrings; there isn't a separate character type) one at a time. The `list` constructor expects any object that can do this, and constructs a list that contains the elements thus provided.